# Optimset function exists in Matlab, is there a Python equivalent?

Tags: python, matlab, implementation

I am trying to translate some Matlab code into Python. The following is the particular line I want to translate.

```
options = optimset('Display','off','Diagnostics','off','MaxIter',2000,'TolFun',1e-10,'TolX',1e-10 )
```

I was wondering if there existed a similar structure in Python. Can someone also explain more about what optimset actually does in this particular case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [optimset](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimset.html) you set the options for an optimization problem solver. [Here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-options-reference.html) you can find details about the options.

```
'Display','off', - displays no output.
'Diagnostics','off', - does not display any diagnostics
'MaxIter',2000, - Maximum number of iterations allowed is set to 2000.
'TolFun',1e-10, - Termination tolerance on the function value.
'TolX',1e-10 - Termination tolerance on x.
```

How to do this in python depends on the package you want to use. You can e.g. use [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html) which provides a wide range of solvers for all kinds of problems.